# IOS UIImage Image upside down

Tags: ios, uiimage, jpeg, draw

if i draw my image I fixed the problem use CGAffintrasform

```
CGAffineTransform myTr = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, backImage.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, myTr);
[backImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(cbx, -cby, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height)];
myTr = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, backImage.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, myTr);
```

when i wanna write to file
i use this

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(backImage, 0);
```

then Image upside down
how ?

Comment: Where do you get the backImage from? Can't you just flip the context there using a transform once?

Comment: i draw it ,like CGContextBeginPath.... CGContextMove..(0,0) CGContextAddLines....CGContextFillPath.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to get a UIImage to save, use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, isOpaque, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){ {0,0}, origSize }, [origImage CGImage]);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Then do:

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(backImage, 0);
```

Comment: Apple tells us over and over again at WWDC to use the above when rendering images.

Answer (score 2):

First make Identity matrix.

```
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
0, 0, 1

CGAffineTransform matrix = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Move position for drawing...

```
matrix = CGAffineTransformTranslate(matrix, x, y);
```

Flip matrix horizontal.

```
matrix = CGAffineTransformScale(matrix, -1, 1);
```

Flip matrix vertical.

```
matrix = CGAffineTransformScale(matrix, 1, -1);
```

Rotate matrix

```
matrix = CGAffineTransformRotate(matrix, angle);
```

Fit scale UIImage to UIView.

```
matrix = CGAffineTransformScale(matrix, imageWidth/viewWidth, imageheight/viewHeight);
```

Launch matrix into the context.

```
CGContextConcatCTM(context, matrix);
```

Draw image.

```
[backImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

:)