# Convert UIBezierPath to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, watchkit, uibezierpath

I'm creating a Apple Watch.So I accompanying a Iphone app in which I draw  a Pie-graph using **UIBezierPath**. And i need to convert that graph to **UIImage**. Here is the code what i tried:

**GraphView.m**

```
 rectImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 260)];

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectImage.frame.size);

 CGFloat arcRadious = OUTER_RADIOUS;
 CGFloat tmpStartAngle = startAngle;
 CGFloat tmpEndAngle = endAngle;

 UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
 path.lineWidth = 23;

 [path addArcWithCenter:centre radius:arcRadious startAngle:tmpStartAngle endAngle:tmpEndAngle clockwise:YES];

 [(UIColor*)_fillColours[index] setStroke];
 [path stroke];

 CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
 image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsPopContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But in Apple Watch only some portion of the graph is showing. Can anyone tell me what wrong i did. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408209/how-to-create-a-image-with-uibezierpath/40908425#40908425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are a few things wrong here - let's break it down bit by bit.

---

#### 1: Creating The Context

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectImage.frame.size);
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here.

What you're doing is getting the current context from the top of the stack (which might not even exist), then you're trying to push that context onto the stack again - which makes no sense as it's *already* on the stack (it's the current context!).

Then you're creating your image context, which will automatically push it onto the stack - making it the current context.

Therefore I'm assuming what you meant to do is this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectImage.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

This will create a new image context, make it the current context, and then get a reference to it.

---

#### 2: Creating The Path

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path addArcWithCenter:centre radius:arcRadious startAngle:tmpStartAngle endAngle:tmpEndAngle clockwise:YES];
```

This could be problematic as you never move the path to a point before adding your arc - therefore it might not be drawn correctly.

You'll therefore want to move it to the arc's center point before adding it.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
[path moveToPoint:centre];
[path addArcWithCenter:centre radius:arcRadious startAngle:tmpStartAngle endAngle:tmpEndAngle clockwise:YES];
```

---

#### 3: Drawing The Path

```
[(UIColor*)_fillColours[index] setStroke];
[path stroke];

CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath); // <- Remove
```

Your third line here is unnecessary. This is because the `stroke` method on the `UIBezierPath` actually adds the bezier path to the current context and then strokes the path in that context.

---

#### 4: Ending The Context

```
UIGraphicsPopContext(); // <- Remove
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Again, the image context will handle popping itself off the stack when you call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`, so trying to pop it yourself may cause issues.

---

#### Lastly, some pedantic details.

```
rectImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 260)];
```

Seeing as you're working with images in this code, the name `rectImage` is fairly misleading, as it's a `UIView`. I would rename to `rectView`.

```
CGFloat arcRadious = OUTER_RADIOUS;
```

I sincerely hope that `OUTER_RADIOUS` isn't a macro (`#define`). Constants **should not** be defined with a macro - they're not type safe and can make debugging a nightmare. Avoid them like the plague.

Instead, you should be using a `static` C constant. For example:

```
static CGFloat const kOuterRadius = 100.0
```

Comment: can u tell me how to display these images in Apple Watch using **Page-Based Navigation**

Comment: @JestinSajiChacko Please try not ask more than one question per post - it generates confusion and generally isn't beneficial for future readers. I would go ahead and ask a new question about page navigation on the Apple Watch, and rollback this question to being about rendering a `UIBezierPath` in an image context.

Comment: Ok. As u said i asked another question about Page-Based Navigation